# virtualenv error osx 10.9.5

Tags: python, macos, flask, virtualenv

I'm trying to follow [Miguel Grinberg's flask tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world), and the first step is to create a virtual environment. When I attempt this, I get errors. I'm using Python 2.7 on osx 10.9.5, and my Xcode and command line tools are up to date.

Here's the code:

```
$ python virtualenv.py flask
Using base prefix '/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-       
x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents'
New python executable in flask/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/adamkalman/Desktop/microblog/flask/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable flask/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/Users/adamkalman/Desktop/microblog' (should be     
u'/Users/adamkalman/Desktop/microblog/flask')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

What is going on here? Is there a fix for this? (I'm very ignorant in this domain.) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Canopy and virtualenv aren't compatible. Your two options are

1. Don't use Canopy
2. [Use venv](https://support.enthought.com/entries/21802240-Use-venv-not-virtualenv-with-Canopy-Python)

Comment: Thanks dirn! This solved my problem! I just used venv instead.